# Setting up MIM, should I split up DC, SQL, Sharepoint, MIM on different VMs?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I am following Microsofts [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/microsoft-identity-manager-deploy) to set up a MIM Server. I understand that the AD DC Server should be a standalone VM. But what about SQL, Sharepoint, and MIM? Should these share one Virtual Machine? And if they should, how do I get the installation files?

In the guide all it says is "Install SQL", or "Install Sharepoint". Since I'm a beginner I'm not sure if they mean in a new VM or in the existing one that I set up under step "Server Setup: Windows Server"?

The way I think they mean is:

- VM 1 - AD DC
- VM 2 - Windows Server for MIM
- VM 3 - SQL Server
- VM 4 - Sharepoint Server
- VM 5 - Exchange Server (optional)

However, this seems like a lot of work just to set up MIM, is my thinking right or can you put MIM, SQL, SP and Exchange on the same server, and should you?

Answer (score 0):

You could check [Environment overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/pam/environment-overview) and [Hardware and software requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/pam/hardware-software-requirements) firstly.

[image]

> You need a minimum of three virtual machines. If you don't already
>   have an AD domain for PAM to manage, you need one additional VM to act
>   as a CORP domain controller. If you wish to configure the PRIV
>   software for high availability, you need two additional VMs.

Based on my understanding, you could install MIM, SQL, Sharepoint  in a same Windows server. But for better performance, you could install them on different Windows Server.

> In the guide all it says is "Install SQL", or "Install Sharepoint".

You need download SQL and Sharepoint installer from Microsoft download center and install them following [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/microsoft-identity-manager-deploy).

Comment: Hi, does it work for you? If it helps, please don't forget to accept it as an answer so that other community members will be benefited, thanks:)